# Python tic-tac-toe - if statement query

Tags: python

I created a tic-tac-toe program for 2 players but when the conditions are met, python would not break:

```
def display_board(moves):
    print (' ' + moves[0] + '  | ' + moves[1] + '  | ' + moves[2])
    print ('---- ---- ----')
    print (' ' + moves[3] + '  | ' + moves[4] + '  | ' + moves[5])
    print ('---- ---- ----')
    print (' ' + moves[6] + '  | ' + moves[7] + '  | ' + moves[8])
    
moves = ('         ')

turn = 1

player = 'X'

def play_move(moves, row, col, turn):
    if turn % 2 == 1:
        player = 'X'
    else:
        player = 'O'
    pos = (3 * (row - 1) + col) - 1
    moves = moves[:pos] + player + moves[pos + 1:]
    return moves

game_end = False

if moves[0] == moves[1] and moves[1] == moves[2] and moves[0] != ' ':
    game_end = True
if moves[3] == moves[4] and moves[4] == moves[5] and moves[3] != ' ':
    game_end = True
if moves[6] == moves[7] and moves[7] == moves[8] and moves[6] != ' ':
    game_end = True    
if moves[0] == moves[3] and moves[3] == moves[6] and moves[0] != ' ':
    game_end = True
if moves[1] == moves[4] and moves[4] == moves[7] and moves[0] != ' ':
    game_end = True
if moves[2] == moves[5] and moves[5] == moves[8] and moves[0] != ' ':
    game_end = True
if moves[0] == moves[4] and moves[4] == moves[8] and moves[0] != ' ':
    game_end = True    
if moves[2] == moves[4] and moves[4] == moves[6] and moves[2] != ' ':
    game_end = True

while not game_end:
    display_board(moves)
    row = int(input('Please enter the row number: '))
    col = int(input('Please enter the column number: '))
    moves = play_move(moves, row, col, turn)
    turn += 1
    if game_end == True:
        break
```

[Link to code in a live environment](https://repl.it/JomY/0)

Comment: Put all the `if` statements inside the `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a classic infinite loop. You are checking whether the game has ended only once: before starting the game!

```
game_end = False

if moves[0] == moves[1] and moves[1] == moves[2] and moves[0] != ' ':
    game_end = True
if moves[3] == moves[4] and moves[4] == moves[5] and moves[3] != ' ':
    game_end = True
if moves[6] == moves[7] and moves[7] == moves[8] and moves[6] != ' ':
    game_end = True    
if moves[0] == moves[3] and moves[3] == moves[6] and moves[0] != ' ':
    game_end = True
if moves[1] == moves[4] and moves[4] == moves[7] and moves[0] != ' ':
    game_end = True
if moves[2] == moves[5] and moves[5] == moves[8] and moves[0] != ' ':
    game_end = True
if moves[0] == moves[4] and moves[4] == moves[8] and moves[0] != ' ':
    game_end = True    
if moves[2] == moves[4] and moves[4] == moves[6] and moves[2] != ' ':
    game_end = True


while not game_end:
    display_board(moves)
    row = int(input('Please enter the row number: '))
    col = int(input('Please enter the column number: '))
    moves = play_move(moves, row, col, turn)
    turn += 1
    if game_end == True:
        break
```

After starting the loop at `while not game_end`, it will never step, since you are not changing the variable `game_end` *inside* the loop:

```
game_end = False
while not game_end:
    display_board(moves)
    row = int(input('Please enter the row number: '))
    col = int(input('Please enter the column number: '))
    moves = play_move(moves, row, col, turn)
    turn += 1

    game_end = False
    if moves[0] == moves[1] and moves[1] == moves[2] and moves[0] != ' ':
        game_end = True
    if moves[3] == moves[4] and moves[4] == moves[5] and moves[3] != ' ':
        game_end = True
    if moves[6] == moves[7] and moves[7] == moves[8] and moves[6] != ' ':
        game_end = True    
    if moves[0] == moves[3] and moves[3] == moves[6] and moves[0] != ' ':
        game_end = True
    if moves[1] == moves[4] and moves[4] == moves[7] and moves[1] != ' ':
        game_end = True
    if moves[2] == moves[5] and moves[5] == moves[8] and moves[2] != ' ':
        game_end = True
    if moves[0] == moves[4] and moves[4] == moves[8] and moves[0] != ' ':
        game_end = True    
    if moves[2] == moves[4] and moves[4] == moves[6] and moves[2] != ' ':
        game_end = True
```

Comment: @JavKoh That's because some of the conditions are wrong.  Look at the last part in each condition – some of them are `moves[0]` when they should actually be something else.  You should refactor this code to be less repetitive, since repeating yourself is always error-prone.

Comment: One simple way to reduce the amount of repetition (though you can do much more) is to use operator chaining. A line like `if moves[0] == moves[1] == moves[2] != ' ':` is almost exactly equivalent to your existing code (the middle values get compared with the values on each side and the results are all combined with `and`).

Answer (score 0):

**Better Solution**

The better solution is that use a new function for check ending game in `while` :

```
while not game_ended(moves):
    display_board(moves)
    row = int(input('Please enter the row number: '))
    col = int(input('Please enter the column number: '))
    moves = play_move(moves, row, col, turn)
    turn += 1
```

or:

```
while game_in_progress(moves):
    display_board(moves)
    row = int(input('Please enter the row number: '))
    col = int(input('Please enter the column number: '))
    moves = play_move(moves, row, col, turn)
    turn += 1
```

Now, you can move all `if` statements to the new function.

or according the law `DRY` ([Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) use another function to check conditions too:

```
def match_three(moves, match1, match2, match3):
    return moves[match1] == moves[match2] and moves[match2] == moves[match3] and moves[match1] != ' ':

def game_in_progress(moves):
    if match_three(moves, 0, 1, 2): return true
    if match_three(moves, 3, 4, 5): return true
    ... # other conditions

    return false # no match_three was accepted
```

or:

```
def match_three(moves, matches):
    return moves[matches[0]] == moves[matches[1]] and moves[matches[2]] == moves[matches[0]] and moves[match1] != ' ':

def game_in_progress(moves):
    if match_three(moves, (0, 1, 2)): return true
    if match_three(moves, (3, 4, 5)): return true
    ... # other conditions

    return false # no match_three was accepted
```

This makes it so that when one condition is `true` the check for the rest is ignored.

Also you can use a tuple (or list) of last_moves to check via a loop. But I guess that isn't related your questions.